# How to install slocate in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, software-installation, locate

I have seen several references to the `slocate` command [[1]](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/slocate-command-in-linux/)[[2]](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/ubuntu-63/slocate-364057/) as a more secure alternative to the `locate` command.  However I cannot install it using `sudo apt install slocate`.  I also cannot find any references on how to install it for Ubuntu and only one reference to [installing it on any Linux platform at all](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/slocate-command-620853/). But [here is a question](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/ubuntu-63/slocate-364057/) about how to use it and it is also [referenced in official Ubuntu manual](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/updatedb.findutils.1.html).

So, why is it referenced, but not available? Must it be [installed from source only](https://sources.debian.org/src/slocate/3.1-1/src/)?

Comment: The reference in the manual is only that the GNU tool supports the slocate db format. GNU tools are not exclusive to Linux, they run on a variety of systems, so it's not unusual that the support a variety of things even if those are not usually seen on Linux

Comment: And your links are antiques. The forum posts are 18, 19, and 18 years old, the Debian link is for a 16 year old release.

Comment: Yes, noticed that the link were ancient, and that the manual only points to support for the `slocate` database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can’t install it (without building it from source), it’s no longer available. Current alternatives are better so you wouldn’t want to anyway.

`slocate` was “secure” a long time ago. However its developer stopped working on the project, and it had various bugs. Distributions moved on, first to [`mlocate`](https://pagure.io/mlocate) and now to [`plocate`](https://plocate.sesse.net/).

After over a year in limbo, [`slocate` was removed from Debian in January 2009](https://bugs.debian.org/457565). Ubuntu would have followed suit shortly thereafter.

Comment: Thanks for the awesome explanation and tip about plocate.